# How are these negative values understood?

Tags: effect-size

I can't find literature to understand this table. 
What I know doing my research is that an effect size should be between 0 and 1. when 0.2 is slow, 0,5 medium and 0.8 and higher , high. But In an article of Cochrane database I found these results and I can't really make a sense of this. I need this really badly so anyone who can help me to understand these values (including those ranges in brackets) I'd really appreciate it.

[image: Effect size]

Comment: It appears that you are looking at Cohen's $d$ as a measure of effect size; at least, your definitions of "low", "medium" and "high" are the ones Cohen proposed for his $d$. As per [Alexis' answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113521/1352), you can simply flip signs for negative $d$, keeping the interpretation in mind. However, note that $d$ is not constrained to be below 1 - $d>1$ is perfectly possible!

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** the effects you describe as slow [sic], medium and higher are *protective effects* where patients treated with the drug experience *less* psychotic outcomes (or side effects or whatever these studies are comparing), a negative value would imply that a patient experienced *more* psychotic outcomes (or side effects, whatever outcomes, etc.) than placebo... in other words: negative values denote *harm*, the degree to which they do so is likely inverted from the positive values (e.g. -0.8 and lower is a higher negative effect than >–0.8 to -0.5, etc.).

Of the four rows you show, Aripiprazole appears to be the only drug with confidence bounds (the numbers in the brackets) that are purely negative, implying that it is the only one for which such evidence of negative effect was found. Because the confidence intervals of the other three span zero more or less evenly, you would not say that you had evidence of a positive or negative effect.

If the assumption I stated on the first line of this answer is incorrect, and a higher positive number means a higher bad outcome (say longer psychotic episode, more unwanted side effects, etc. for whatever these studies are about that you are not telling us... **hint hint** "edit" button in lower left of your question. **hint hint** :), then the interpretation I just gave is also inverted (i.e. placebo would have higher bad outcomes/drug would have a protective effect).